# react-css-modules & karma without ExtractTextPlugin

Tags: jasmine, karma-runner, css-modules, react-css-modules

I have react-css-modules working on my app with webpack which generates a compiled .css file using ExtractTextPlugin which I serve up.  Everything works fine but I'm stuck on how to get it work with karma/jasmine?

I keep getting CSS Module is undefined when this error doesn't occuer when building on webpack.

This is my karma config, the only difference is that I dont use ExtractTextPlugin

ie for `test: /(((activityFeed|fonts)\.css)|(grids-core\.css)|(grids-responsive\.css))$/` I have `loader: ['style', 'css?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]']`

```
var webpackConfigModified = {
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: 'babel',
        query: {
          loose: ['all'],
          modules: 'commonStrict',
          optional: ['runtime', 'minification.propertyLiterals']
        }
      },
      {
        test: /(\.css)$/,
        exclude: ['./node_modules/purecss/build', './app/client/main/stylesheets'],
        loader: 'style!css'
      },
      {
        test: /(((activityFeed|fonts)\.css)|(grids-core\.css)|(grids-responsive\.css))$/,
        include: ['./node_modules/purecss/build', './app/client/main/stylesheets'],
        loader: ['style', 'css?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]']
      },
      {
        test: /underscore(?:-min)?\.js$/,
        loader: 'expose?underscore'
      },
      {
        test: require.resolve('lodash'),
        loader: 'expose?lodash'
      },
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: 'json-loader'
      }
    ],
    noParse: []
  },
  plugins: [],
  externals: {
    jsdom: 'window',
    cheerio: 'window',
    'react/lib/ExecutionEnvironment': true,
    'react/lib/ReactContext': 'window',
    'text-encoding': 'window'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.json', '.css', '.scss'],
    alias: {
      'purecss/build/grids-responsive.css': path.resolve('./node_modules', 'purecss/build/grids-responsive.css'),
      'purecss/build/grids-core.css': path.resolve('./node_modules', 'purecss/build/grids-core.css')
    },
    fallback: path.resolve('./app/client/'),
  }
};

  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine-ajax', 'jasmine'],
    files: [
      { pattern: 'app/client/spec/**/*.spec.js', watched: true, served: true, included: true },
    ],
    preprocessors: {
      './app/client/spec/**/*.spec.js': ['webpack']
    },
    exclude: [
    ],
    webpack: webpackConfigModified,
    webpackServer: {
      noInfo: true,
      stats: 'errors-only'
    },
    plugins: [
      'karma-*'
    ],
    reporters: ['progress'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    autoWatchBatchDelay: 800,
    browsers: ['Chrome', 'Firefox'],
    singleRun: false
  });
```